# HTML Form Mailto Output Formatting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mailto

I'm having a little trouble defining my question.  Here's what I have.

- A mailto form with some fancy Javascript elements.
- Upon submission of this form, I want to format the data submitted to be more readable.

For instance, when I submit the form, the e-mail body text is displayed as such:

```
NAME1="value"
NAME2="value"
NAME3="value"
```

What I want is for it to be formatted in a table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>"value"</td>
    <td>"value"</td>
    <td>"value"</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

I'm at the point where I know to have my submit button onClick to some script which would then output it to the format I want, but can't figure out where to go from there.  If anyone can just point me in the right direction, I should be able to figure it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible

Use a server and send as HTML

Using mailto you can only do %0D%0A for line feed

Like this:

```
<form 
onsubmit="location='mailto:'+this.email.value+
'?subject='+escape(this.subject.value)+
'&body=Name:'+escape(this.name.value)+'%0D%0A'+ 
'Address:'+escape(this.address.value); return false">
```

Comment: Server side scripting is not an option for the time being.  

Is it possible to get some Javascript function to use the value of an input/option and then output it to text with .innerHTML or strOutput?

Comment: Sure but no HTML in the mailto